# My domain is well indexed but only in my country

Tags: google-index

This is my domain: http://yon.ir and it mainly should be shown in search results with the keyword "کوتاه کننده لینک"
If you search from Iran it is shown in Google's search results with rank 13 (with that keyword) which is logical but with IPs of other countries, it's not shown even in the first 10 Google result pages. The domain is indexed and when I search the whole domain title, it shows up my site on the first page.

It's been like this for about 10 days and the domain is not new. It was working with its previous owner before.

So, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information you provide, there's no "problem" at all that I can see. Overall, this is entirely correct behavior.

You have a a domain whose TLD is intended for entities connected with Iran, and whose content is in Farsi[1]. So sure, its ranking is going to get a boost when searched for from Iran.

Conversely, if I do search from a US-based IP address and have no particular history of Farsi search terms or even related content, it's entirely reasonable that it might not rank as high as other sites that may, for example, be taking additional steps to gain an international audience, etc.

[1] Sorry if that's inaccurate; I used a language detector. Let me know and I'll correct. At any rate, we can generalize this to "non-English" for purposes of my answer.

Comment: well , if you look more accurate , all results showing up with this keyword with a US-based IP, are Persian websites. This is really common in Iran because of widely filtering of websites like facebook , twitter , ... to use VPN connections to access these websites. So , getting a good rank with foreign IPs is very important. and this is not the first time I index websites with Persian content in Google. They work fine and are shown up in search results when searching with foreign IPs like US-based ones ...

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a ccTLD specific to your country. Google puts more weight on these when ranking those domains within their own country and from their own Google when available.

The language of your website will also affect rankings. When I search that keyword I do not see your website. It's likely the websites ranking in Google.com for that keyword have met more of the qualities google looks for to rank websites.

Compare the number of pages indexed between you and your competitors. The content of these pages ranking high and quality of the content. If possible look at how many back links they have vs your site and how many are coming from authority sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Google Webmasters account, then you can specifically ask Google to focus on a country. So register your site under an account and do not specify the target country. That should help a bit.